# How to push new commits to repository after resetting the head?

Tags: git

I connected to the server via SSH, made wrong changes to the code and committed to git. After this, I removed the wrong commit by

```
git reset --hard <previous_commit_id>
```

after this, I made new commits on my laptop and tried to push them to my server repository

```
git push --force user@server.com:/path/to/project
Everything up-to-date
```

I see *Everything up-to-date*, but on the server, I do not see new commits in **git log**

How can I push from local repo to the server in this case?

Comment: Why did you add a repo path after `git push --force`? It should work without or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First add the add the files you want to commit by using

```
git add .
```

then commit the changes using

```
git commit -m 'Message About commit'
```

then push your local changes on to remote server using

```
git push origin <Branch Name>
```

replace branch name with your remote branch name

Comment: it's not worked for me. I make "git push origin master user@server..." and see "fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in user@server" Earlier, before I maked changes on server all working good

Comment: did you check your .gitconfig file?

Comment: @tolyan: The syntax `git push origin master user@server` is not correct. It's `git push <remote> <refspec>`, e.g., `git push origin master` or `git push ssh://user@server/path/to/repository master`.